# content alignment in datagridview shows Object reference not set error?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to rename the column header of winform datagridview control. My code is :

```
 gridProjectEdit.Columns[0].HeaderText = "S.NO.";
```

It is working well but when i try to adjust content alignment using the line of code:

```
 gridProjectEdit.Columns["S.NO."].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

It shows error that :

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

When i change the column header to SNO only not S.NO. , it works without any problem.
I am doing this in .Net framework 2.0, if it matters.

Please let me know where i am doing mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you just set the **HeaderText**, not the column `Name`, so to fix this you better remember the column Name and use it in the code or use the `index` (although this is not really recommended in some cases for the unclear code). If your grid has unique Column `HeaderText` (which is the usual case), you can search for the Column by `HeaderText` using a little of `LINQ`:

```
gridProjectEdit.Columns.OfType<DataGridViewColumn>()
               .FirstOrDefault(col => col.HeaderText == "S.NO.")
               .DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment
                                            .MiddleCenter;
```